# What topics to learn(cover) in Asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am at a beginner level on Asp.MVC 3. If any one could suggest me on what things one should know in Asp.Net-MVC. i am about to give some interviews to get a job to have a clear idea on what recriuters ask and what should i must learn to get a job in Asp.net MVC

please suggest me some topics..

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I bet this one get's closed...

Comment: Do you want to learn asp.net mvc or just to get the job?

Comment: i want to learn and then want to get a job...

Comment: @Bazz: whats wrong in this question? if i dont know anything and i am asking for the help.. i dont think that i did anything wrong...anyways...

Comment: well, what he means is that this site is for questions about programming. Specific issues that can be solved with codes or close. Your question is kindda abstract if u know what I mean :)

Comment: @kasper: thx man.. but wat i basically meant was i am looking for a detailed tutorials on mvc 3 ...

Comment: btw I love that you have jquery as a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/mvc

Pluralsight's tutorials with all the basic and important topics. Also microsofts own documentation.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment... i have already completed that tutorials and want to get in more details...

Comment: @patel Sorry dont have knowlegde of any more detailed tutorials. Most of the common issues and problem are here on stackoverflow though.

Answer (score 1):

As adviced, http://www.asp.net/mvc is good starting point. You should also check out the [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com) and [MvcMusicStore](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) live examples.

There're currently two active books about ASP.NET MVC 3 (Latest version). Both good to get in depth knowledge of every aspect in framework. In fact, reading at least one of them is required if you want to get professional in framework.

- [Professional ASP.NET MVC 3 (Wrox Programmer to Programmer) by Jon Galloway, Phil Haack, Brad Wilson and K. Scott Allen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118076583)
- [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework by Steven Sanderson and Adam Freeman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040)

And the last point - read articles, blogs, etc. From SO tag description:

> Latest announcements from Microsoft usually come from Scott Guthrie's
>   [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/). Other notable blogs relating to MVC include [Phil
>   Haack](http://haacked.com/), [Scott Hanselman](http://hanselman.com), and [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/).